# Trouble understanding C++ pointer syntax

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

I'm not able to understand this statement of code that I came across during my interview.

```cpp
int(*(*ptr[3])(char*))[2];
```

I've tried looking at an IDE but all I have is that it is an array of data type

```cpp
int (*(*[3])(char *))
```

I wasn't able to understand this.

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? What have you tried to resolve this? Are you familiar with function pointer declarations?

Comment: [This tool](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*%28*f%5B3%5D%29%28char+*%29%29%5B3%5D) is often helpful.

Comment: What you have is wrong. Declarations are read from the inside out, not outside in.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/cdecl1.html

Comment: @melpomene outside-in works better for me; if you have the type without the name (e.g. `int(*(*[3])(char*))[2]` here) it may not even be clear where the middle is! I would approach that type by noting that  it is of the form  `int(..........)[2]`  which I would solve by working out  `int ........` (via same method recursively)  and then replacing `int` with "array of 2 `int`s".

Comment: @M.M That means you need to keep a stack somewhere. With `int *a[2][7]` the solution is "`a` is an array[2] of array[7] of pointer to `int`". If you don't start at `a` and work your way outwards, you need to remember "pointer to", "array of 7", and "array of 2" somewhere until you reach `a` and can assemble the thing backwards.

Comment: @melpomene Right, as a C++ coder stack unwinding comes naturally ;)

Comment: I think it might help you see how a pointer to an explicitly-sized array is declared in C, which is something we don't see every day (or at least me): `int (*arrptr)[2];` to use as `(*arrptr)[0] `. Of course everything would have been clearer with a couple of typedefs: `typedef int ret_t[2];` and `typedef ret_t * (*fptr_t)(char *);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you could just break it down one at a time to understand the syntax better. First start up with a simple definition without the array notation

```
int(*(*ptr)(char*));
```

So `ptr` is a function pointer that takes a `char` pointer as an argument and returns a pointer to an `int`. Now extending it to the array notation

```
int(*(*ptr[3])(char*))[2];
```

which means you have an array of function pointers, each of which will take a `char` pointer argument and return a pointer to an array of two integers.

You can see this working if you have a make a function call using these pointers you define. Note that, the below functions are for demonstrative purposes only and do not convey any logical purpose

```
#include <iostream>

static int arr[2] = { 2, 2 };

// initialize  'bar' as a function that accepts char* and returns
// int(*)[2]
int (*bar(char * str))[2] {
    return &arr;
}

int main() {
    // pointer definition, not initialized yet
    int(*(*foo[3])(char*))[2];
    char ch = 'f';
    // as long as the signatures for the function pointer and 
    // bar matches, the assignment below shouldn't be a problem
    foo[0] = bar;
    // invoking the function by de-referencing the pointer at foo[0]
    // Use 'auto' for C++11 or declare ptr as int (*ptr)[2] 
    auto *ptr = (*foo[0])(&ch);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to unfold the type from the inside out and recall that `[]` and `()` (on the right) bind stronger than `*` (on the left). To override this binding, parentheses `()` are used.

```
int(*(*ptr[3])(char*))[2];
^   ^ ^^  ^   ^       ^
|   | ||  |   |       |
|   | |ptr is |       |
|   | |   |   |       |
|   | |   an array of three
|   | |       |       |
|   | pointers to     |
|   |         |       |
|   |         a function taking a char* and returning
|   |                 |
|   a pointer to      |
|                     an array of two
ints
```

i.e. "`ptr` is an array of three pointers to a function taking a `char*` and returning a pointer to an array of two `int`s".

Comment: This is like a maze ++