# how to understand the syntax `Color (&EnumValuesColor())[3] {...}`?

Tags: c++, syntax

this is an auto generated header (by flatbuffer serializer) and I've never seen any syntax like `Color (&EnumValuesColor())[3] {...}` could someone explain it ?

```cpp
enum Color {
  Color_Red = 0,
  Color_Green = 1,
  Color_Blue = 2,
  Color_MIN = Color_Red,
  Color_MAX = Color_Blue
};

inline const Color (&EnumValuesColor())[3] {
  static const Color values[] = {
    Color_Red,
    Color_Green,
    Color_Blue
  };
  return values;
}
```

Comment: See also [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602762/trouble-understanding-c-pointer-syntax/57608683#57608683) about parsing types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not surprising that you don't recognise it; this is an example of some *very* arcane declarator shenanigans we inherited from C, relating to the so-called "[spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)".

What's happening here is:

- There is a function called `EnumValuesColor`
- It returns a reference to an array of 3 `const Color`s
- It's marked `inline`

You can use https://cdecl.org to help you parse super-complex declarations like this, though note that you'll have to replace `Color` with `int`, otherwise it won't know you're talking about a type:

[image: Screenshot of this problem solved for us by cdecl.org]

Since C++14, you may prefer to write the function declaration like this instead:

```
inline auto& EnumValuesColor() {
  static const Color values[] = {
    Color_Red,
    Color_Green,
    Color_Blue
  };
  return values;
}
```

Now, in such a small function, just by observing that we directly return a `const Color values[]` (and mentally stick a `3` in there) we can see much more easily what the heck is going on. I am definitely not one of those people who recommends "auto almost always", but this seems like a great use case for it.

As an aside, if you were wondering why bother using a function at all… that's probably to avoid the [static initialisation order fiasco](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). The initialisation of *function* statics is a gazillion times more predictable than for anything declared at namespace scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Color (&EnumValuesColor())[3]
```

is an old-fashioned way of writing

```
auto EnumValuesColor() -> Color const (&)[3]
```

which makes it clearer that `EnumValuesColor` is a function. To read the return type, we read inside out, and right to left, which gives the return type as: a reference to an array of 3 `const Color` objects.